# How to implement autocomplete with top K suggestions algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, autocomplete, heap, ternary-search-tree

This is a question for an interview: Write a program to implement autocomplete for a given set of N strings and positive weights. That is, given a prefix and an integer k, find the top k strings in the set among those that start with the prefix.

And I found a suggested algorithm here with ternary search tree and max heap: http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/fall13/cos226/checklist/autocomplete.html

I kinda get the algorithm but I have no idea how to print out the top K words. One biggest confusion I have is: we can traverse the tree and get all the nodes with max weights, but how do we go back and get the words together?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you know the range of n and k?

Comment: No it is not given but I believe N would be huge, and K will be 10ish

Comment: It is not what the question ask but maybe you can just store the top k words for each nodes if k is small